# Rendering React Component always on the root node

Tags: reactjs

Here is the issue: I have a ModalBaseComponentLayout, what I want to happen every time I call the ModalBaseComponentLayout I want it to always be rendered on the parents.

Let's say, what's happening is:

```
<div id="root">
     <div class="ONE modal fade in">
         <div class="modal-header"></div>
         <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="TWO modal fade in">
                   <div class="modal-header"></div>
                   <div class="modal-content"></div>
                   <div class="modal-footer"></div>
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

What I want to happen is

```
<div id="root">
     <div class="ONE modal fade in">
         <div class="modal-header"></div>
         <div class="modal-content">
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="TWO modal fade in">
         div class="modal-header"></div>
         <div class="modal-content"></div>
         <div class="modal-footer"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

So basically what I want to happen is render my modal component on the root node not the child of the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at React Portals: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Basically this:

```
render() {
  // React does *not* create a new div. It renders the children into `domNode`.
  // `domNode` is any valid DOM node, regardless of its location in the DOM.
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    this.props.children,
    domNode
  );
}
```